# Edit phone number associated with device / SIM

Tags: settings

On my device, when I check the phone number through `Settings` > `About Phone` > `Status` > `SIM Status`, the phone number is incorrect. I ported my number over when I took out a new contract so I guess this is the number originally associated with the SIM. Is there any way to change this?

**EDIT:** Device is a Nexus 6P running M 6.0.1, no root.

Comment: A factory reset ought to fix this if it's not a SIM issue.  I'm sure there is something specific you could clear the data for rather than that nuclear option, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a SIM issue. I've read that it can be "fixed" by using an iPhone or Blackberry as they have the option to change the number. I know you used to be able to on Android but the functionality seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 5):

A SIM contains multiple phonebook sections. One of them stores your SIM contacts. Another section contains "My Numbers" (MSISDN) with a max capacity of 3 numbers, usually.

Unfortunately, my phones are too new to access "My Numbers", and my phones that are old enough (2005) to edit them are out of reach.

Fortunately, I had a spare SIM800 *development board* lying around. [I hooked it up to my Arduino](https://www.factoryforward.com/sim800l-gsm-module-arduino-commands-library/) and started issuing AT commands.

Here's my conversation with my SIM card:

```
AT               <-- Check if we are live and communicating with the SIM

OK

AT+CNUM?         <-- Get own number

ERROR            <-- CNUM failed, we don't have an "own" number

at+cpbs="ON"     <-- Switch to "ON" phonebook: MSISDN (SIM own numbers)

OK

at+cpbs?         <-- Get capacity of current phonebook

+CPBS: "ON",0,3  <-- Notice that there's no stored number (0 out of 3)

OK

at+cpbw=,"+639950001234"    <-- Saving my number

OK

at+cpbs?          <-- Get capacity of current phonebook

+CPBS: "ON",1,3   <-- Number saved (now consuming 1 out of 3 slots)

OK

at+cnum           <-- Get own number

+CNUM: ,"+639950001234",145,,4    <-- CNUM OK

OK

AT

OK
```

Unplugged, then returned SIM to phone. After that, my phone now shows my number `+639950001234` instead of "Unknown".

Answer (score 2):

I have found only two solutions:

1. Get Xposed and then either the app above or this one: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/themes-apps/app-sim-changer-change-registered-sim-t2106490
2. Use an old Nokia/Alcatel phone to edit SIM phone number

Comment: How to do it with old Alcatel or nokia feature phones

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've had to join to answer this, so don't have the reputation to add a comment to Aloha's answer, but anyway... that answer is almost perfect. However, I was recently trying to change the my number using that method, but found that I couldn't access the "ON" phone book. It turns out that you have to switch to local phone books before you can access it ( presumably only on some modems or SIM cards. ) You do this using `AT$QCPBMPREF=1` - after which the "ON" phone book is available. I found this info from the thread [here](https://forums.quectel.com/t/unable-to-access-own-numbers-phonebook/12832).